# I cannot render BottomTab Navigator on each screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I react Native app I'm building I want to always see BottomTab Navigator, on each screen.
Currently it works as I open the Drawer.Navigator from CustomHeader "Menu" button. And once I navigate to component , for example "Profil" then ButtomTab dissapears. I suppose I should change some things in BottomTab but I have no clue how to change it.

This is how NavigationContainer looks like :

```
  <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Main"
      component={DrawerNavigation}
      options={({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          headerTitle: (props) => (
            <CustomHeader navigation={navigation} {...props} />
          ),
          headerStyle: { height: 50 },
        };
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Now the Drawer.Navigator, which renders on pressing Custom Header Button

```
 <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerMenu {...props} />}>
  <Drawer.Screen name="BottomTab" component={BottomTabs} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Profil" component={Profil} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="MojeOgłoszenia" component={Moje_Ogloszenia} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="MojeAkcje" component={MojeAkcje} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Premium" component={Premium} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Kontakt" component={Kontakt} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

And here BottomTabs which I always want to see:

```
 <Tabs.Navigator>
  <Tabs.Screen name="Wykonam" component={Wykonam} />
  <Tabs.Screen name="Zlecę" component={Zlece} />
  <Tabs.Screen name="Wiadomości" component={Wiadomosci} />
  <Tabs.Screen name="Dodaj" component={Dodaj} />
</Tabs.Navigator>
```

and now when I go into "Profil" drawer
[image]

then BottomTabs dissapers
[image]

Comment: [This part in the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/) is explaining how to hide the bottom tabs on specific screens. It also explains how that works, so it could be helpful to you

Comment: Ok. So I understand I should nest DrawerItems inside BottomTabs , correct ?

Comment: Yes, I think that you should nest both `DrawerItems` and `StackItems` inside of `BottomTabs`. `BottomTabs` should be at the top of your navigation stack. So:`NavigationContainer` > `Bottom.Navigator` > `Stack.Navigator` or `Drawer.Navigator`

Comment: Thanks. I will try to figure it out